# What is the most trusted Third party tool for Minting Native Tokens on cardano?

Tags: native-assets, minting

I have come across many Third party minting sites, however, I have a security concern, as per the keys, and policies. So what is the most trusted Third party tool for Minting Native Tokens on cardano?

Answer (score 1):

I've used nft-maker.io and they always have sent me the NFTs that I create. You can also mint them with cardano-cl which is the cheapest and gives you more control.

Comment: Thank you jnprogrammer for responding. I know nft-maker.io they are reputable, however, it's not NFTs that I want to mint. I want to mint Fungible tokens. Thanks for answering

Answer (score 1):

Check CNTools - it's a multifunctional tool for Cardano blockchain.

[image]https://github.com/cardano-community/guild-operators

Comment: Thank you too matcheek I will check it out, seems it can mint Fungible Tokens too. Thanks again